# Why isn't the value of the probability "not defined"?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For the discrete random variable $X$, let $P(X = 1) = 0.2, P(X = 2) = 0.3,$ and $P(X = 3) = 0.3, P(X = 4) = 0.2.$

The value of the distribution function of X at location 1.5 is

$(A) \text{ Not defined }.\\ (B) 0.1.\\ (C) 0.2. \\(D) (A)-(C) \text{ false }.$

The answer in my textbook is $C$.. why? Shouldn't it be $A$ since it's a discrete distribution and $X$ takes on values only as defined above, i.e., $1,2,3,4$? I therefore think it should be "not defined" i.e., the answer should be $A$.

Comment: The answer should be (D): the probability is "ZERO"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct in that the question is not worded well. If it was talking about the [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function), it would not be defined there.

However, when it says "distribution function", it seems to be referring to the "[cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)"  i.e. you are looking for $P(X<1.5)$ which is just $P(X=1)=0.2$

Answer (score 2):

Cumulative distribution function differs from prob. density function in that regard that even though both functions can be discontinuous, only PDF can be undefined for certain values. See that in your case PDF is *only defined* for four values (and therefore undefined for the rest) while CDF can always be calculated for any value.

For example, in your case, using definition of distribution function as
$F(t)=P(X \leq t)$ we have
$$F(1.5)=P(X \leq 1.5)=P(X=1)=0.2$$
because only one value of r.v $X$ is less than or equal to $1.5$. This illustrates the fact that CDF can be calculated at any point, regardless of values for which $X$ is defined (in our case $X$ takes only integer values). We can therefore speculate that answer $A$ is a red herring given only to check if a student understands the difference between density and distribution functions.

See the difference:

1. $F(-100)=P(X\leq-100)=0$ because there's no possibility of $X$ taking negative values since it's defined for positive integers only.
2. $F(5)=P(X \leq 5)=1$ since $X$ can be at most $4$, then surely $P(X \leq 5)$ must be equal to $1$.